# Passing arrays to verilog modules

Tags: verilog

I have a 2D array to pass to module.I have flattened it in 1D array and want to send it to some module for processing.For doing that I declared a 32 bit wide wire and tried passing the values of the 32 bit registers to other modules through it.It gave me an error "Procedural assignment to a non-register is not permitted." I wanted to know if there's any other way of doing this? And how can I rectify the error?

---

@Marty Thanks again.It's working.I have to calculate the mean for 1000 sampled floating point values.I have separate 4 modules for floating point addition arithmetic.I want to send each of these values one by one to the module.For that I am using a for loop.I am able to send it for

```
Float_Add dummyinstance(fpvalue[k]);
```

Where k is some constant.

But not for

```
for(..)
  for(..)
     Mean[i]=Float_Add dummyinstance(fpvalue[i][j])
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're trying to assign to a `wire` within an `always` or `initial` block. Use `assign` if you want to change the value on a `wire`. If you'd prefer to use a procedural block (`initial` or `always`), you'll need to change the type of the port to a `reg`. ie:

```
module processor (
    input wire [31:0] flattened_bus_i,
    output wire [31:0] flattened_bus_w,
    output reg  [31:0] flattened_bus_r
);

    initial begin 
       flattened_bus_r = flattened_bus_i + 32'd1; 
    end

    assign flattened_bus_w = flattened_bus_i + 32'd1;

endmodule
```

In SystemVerilog, you should be able to have 2D arrays as ports.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But a few confusions: Can you declare a port as reg?Isn't that a memory?

Comment: I got it. Missed that previously.

Comment: A 'reg' doesn't necessarily mean that a flip-flop or other memory element is inferred in synthesis. It all depends on how it's used. If there's even the possibility that it's value is read before it is assigned, then it will be an memory element. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653284/how-to-interpret-blocking-vs-non-blocking-assignments-in-verilog for more info.