# Verilog compiler error

Tags: verilog

```
    module router (clock, ValidPacket0, ValidPacket1, ValidPacket2, ValidPacket3, PacketIn0, PacketIn1, PacketIn2, PacketIn3, PacketOut0, PacketOut1, PacketOut2, PacketOut3);

   input   clock;
   input   ValidPacket0, ValidPacket1, ValidPacket2, ValidPacket3;  
   input [7:0] PacketIn0, PacketIn1, PacketIn2, PacketIn3;
   output [7:0] PacketOut0,PacketOut1, PacketOut2, PacketOut3;

   reg [3:0]   bvp, vp;
   reg [1:0]   counter0, counter1, counter2, counter3;
   reg [2:0]   sel0, sel1, sel2, sel3;
   reg [3:0]   zero=0;
   reg [7:0]   addr0, addr1, addr2, addr3, out0, out1, out2, out3l;
   wire        np0, np1, np2, np3;
   wire [7:0]  PacketOut0, PacketOut1, Packetout2, Packetout3;

   always@(posedge clock)
     bvp[0]<=ValidPacket0;
   if (ValidPacket0 && !bvp[0]) vp[0]=1'b1;
   else vp[0]=0;
```

The above code gives me the following error:

```
** Error: proj1a.v(23): near "[": syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting "IDENTIFIER" or "TYPE_IDENTIFIER" or '#' or '('
Line 23 is at the if statement.
```

Any Insight?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you either need to add `begin` and `end` keywords around the statements after `always @(posedge)` (and fix your assignment type, see [How to interpret blocking vs non blocking assignments in Verilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653284)), or you need to add `always @(*)` before the if/else to introduce combinational logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
   always@(posedge clock)
     bvp[0]<=ValidPacket0;
   if (ValidPacket0 && !bvp[0]) vp[0]=1'b1;
   else vp[0]=0;
```

This 'if' block indicates a generate block because it appears at the module level. The code `vp[0]=1'b1;` is a procedural statement which is only allowed inside a procedural block. The compiler is complaining because it is expecting a module or udp instance which would never be an identifier followed by a '['.