# stuck in while loop verilog

Tags: verilog

I seem to have written myself into an infinite loop, either that or that Modelsim does not know what to do with the conditions in this while loop:

```
i = 0;
while(i < 8'b01100100 && !(mem[i] == RC)) begin
   i <= i + 1;
end
```

simulation just cannot get past the conditional line in this while loop, can anyone point to what I am doing wrong?

-edit:
the part of the code that holds the while loop:

```
//if remove credential enable is high
if(RCE == 1'b1) begin
  $display ("%d", RC);
  $display ("%d", mem[i]);
  $display ("%b", !(mem[i] == RC));
    while(i < 8'b01100100 && mem[i] != RC) begin
      i <= i + 1;
    end
    if(i < 8'b01100100) begin
        mem[i] <= 24'b111111111111111111111111;
    end else begin
        //do nothing
    end
    i = 0;
    end else begin
        //do nothing
    end
```

this part is inside of an always block with the sensitivity list of posedge clk and posedge rst.

Comment: How many bits is `i`? Can you post the whole file if it's not too large?

Comment: i is 8 bits wide, the whole code is 194 lines long... if you need more of the code, I am more than happy do oblige

Comment: There is a line with `i = 0;` is this meant to be there. For synthesis  you should be able to unroll your loops, I do not see how this would work in your current code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a blocking assignment rather than a non-blocking assignment in the while loop (see [How to interpret blocking vs non blocking assignments in Verilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653284/how-to-interpret-blocking-vs-non-blocking-assignments-in-verilog)).

The non-blocking assignment schedules `i` to be updated after active event processing has completed. However, active event processing will never complete, because the `while` condition will continue to evaluate as true.

Alternatively, you could add delay within the while loop: `@(posedge clk) i <= i + 1`.

Comment: I still think the NBA is the problem, did you try doing `i = i + 1` instead? While the general rule is to use NBAs in edge-sensitive always blocks, that rule isn't always valid for non-synthesizable code like you've shown.