# difference between blocking and non blocking statements with intra-assignment delay

Tags: verilog, blocking, nonblocking

What is the difference between the following 2 snippets of verilog code?

1)

```
always@(in)
  out = #5 in;
```

AND

2)

```
 always@(in)
   out <= #5 in;
```

Considering no other lines are present in the always block, can there be any difference in output? 
question is in reference to slide 16 (see o5 and o6 outputs)
http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/papers/1996-CUG-presentation_nonblocking_assigns.pdf

Answer (score 3):

`out = #5 in;` blocks the next operation for 5 time units. It will prevent the monitoring of the next `@(in)` until the the 5 time units have passed. If you add a `$display` statement just before and after the assignment you will see 5 time units has passed.

```
always @(in) begin
    $display("enter @ %0t",$realtime);
    out = #5 in;
    $display("exit @ %0t",$realtime);
end
/*******************
 * Example output:
 * enter @ time 10
 * exit @ time 15
 *******************/
```

`out <= #5 in;` schedules the assignment of occur 5 time units in the future and allows the next operation to begin without waiting for assignment to complete.

```
always @(in) begin
    $display("enter @ %0t",$realtime);
    out <= #5 in;
    $display("exit @ %0t",$realtime);
end
/*******************
 * Example output:
 * enter @ time 10
 * exit @ time 10
 *******************/
```

Working example at the EDA Playground: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/6/114

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, it helped! Related question : Is `#5 out = in;` EXACTLY the same as `#5 out <= in;` ? I tried it out using your edaplayground example, and they seem to give the same entry-exit times (and also the same waveforms for `out`). However I was wondering if there is some other difference.

Comment: A delay in-front of a statement is always considered an blocking statement. Basically Verilog infers a semicolon; `#5 out ...` is the same as `#5; out ...`. Blocking (`=`) and non-blocking (`<=`) differences still apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653284/how-to-interpret-blocking-vs-non-blocking-assignments-in-verilog

Answer (score 1):

They produce different output when `in` toggles before the `#5` delay is up. The non-blocking assignment will always delay `in` by `#5` regardless of how fast `in` toggles.

Examples on EDA Playground. Note the difference in sim output.

- [Blocking assignment](http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/112)
- [Non-Blocking assignment](http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/113)