# Verilog: Assigning a register to a register

Tags: verilog, variable-assignment

In the below Verilog assignment register `rotationDoneR` is assigned to the Signal and then the other register `rotationDoneRR` is assigned to the same register. Doesn't that mean that both registers hold the same value and the condition is never true?

```
input wire RotationDone; // from the module definition

reg rotationDoneR;
reg rotationDoneRR;

rotationDoneR <= RotationDone; 
rotationDoneRR <= rotationDoneR;  

if ( rotationDoneR && (! rotationDoneRR ) ) begin 
    InterruptToCPU <= 1; 
end
```

Thanks for any clarification!

Answer (score 4):

I ***assume*** there is some **procedural block** based on the **edge of clocking event** in your code.

When you have **non blocking assignments** (`<=`), the **evaluation of RHS** takes place in **Active Event Region**, while the **LHS** is updated in the **NBA region**.

Consider the following example, the non-blocking assignments evaluates RHS in Active region and stores the value **internally**, temporarily for the same time stamp (the **older value** of `a` is stored internally here). Then in the NBA region, the LHS are updated (`b` gets the older value of `a` and `a` gets the value of `inp`).

```
// synthesize to simple wire
a = inp;
b = a;

// synthesize to shift register
a <= inp;
b <= a;
```

Similarly, here `rotationDoneRR` is the **flop-ed version** of `rotationDoneR`. Since, on some clock edge, `rotationDoneR` is loaded with `RotationDone` and at the same time, `rotationDoneRR` is loaded with `rotationDoneR`.

So, the `if` condition evaluates true whenever: The **current input value** is TRUE (current input `RotationDone` = `1'b1`) ***and*** **negated previous value of input** (previous input `RotationDone` = `1'b0`) is satisfied.

Refer to non-blocking assignments [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455750/difference-between-blocking-and-non-blocking-statements-with-intra-assignment-de) and [many other PDFs](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/IIT-MADRAS/CAD_for_VLSI_Design_I/pdf/nptel-cad1-14.pdf) over the net, including [CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA_rev1_2 Paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA_rev1_2.pdf) for more information.