# Verilog/VHDL - How to avoid resetting data registers within a single always block?

Tags: asynchronous, vhdl, verilog, reset, synchronous

I like to avoid resetting data registers that don't need to be reset. For example, when streaming data through pipeline stages, if each stage has a valid bit, there is no need to reset the data registers. (I believe this eases routing and timing on the data registers.)

This can easily be accomplished by using separate always blocks (or processes in vhdl), but I find this verbose, and doing the following is problematic because the data register is essentially being enabled by the reset.

```
always @(posedge clk)
if (rst)
  out_valid <= 0;
  // NOTE: out_data is not reset
else begin
  out_valid <= in_valid;
  if (in_valid)
    out_data <= in_data + 1;
end
```

Instead, I've been putting the reset clause at the end of the always block and taking advantage of the "last assignment wins" rule.

```
always @(posedge clk)
begin
  out_valid <= in_valid;
  if (in_valid)
    out_data <= in_data + 1;

  if (rst)
    out_valid <= 0
end
```

I haven't seen a lot of people using this style. Are there any drawbacks or issues that I'm missing? Is there a better way of doing this?

**Bonus Question**: What if the reset is asynchronous? As in:

```
always @(posedge clk, posedge rst)
begin
  out_valid <= in_valid;
  if (in_valid)
    out_data <= in_data + 1;

  if (rst)
    out_valid <= 0
end
```

In this case I think the synthesizer will connect the reset signal to the data register, which defeats the purpose. Is there an elegant way of decoupling the data register from the reset signal without resorting to separate always block?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'using separate always blocks'

Comment: I would recommend just using two always blocks. There's no way to make it work with an asynchronous reset, and even if you have sync reset, the non-standard usage may confuse some synthesizers (and some engineers!).

Comment: @Morgan, I mean one always block with a reset for the valid register and a separate always block without a reset for the data regsiters.

Comment: @Tim, I guess I want to understand why this isn't standard practice. What are the synthesis tool issues? There seem to be clear advantages of doing it this way  as there is less verbosity and more control of how things are logically grouped together.

Comment: @mksuth FYI I've updated my answer to include some examples for asynchronous resets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Synchronous Resets

I've been using the "*last assignment wins*" for resets for >5 years.  Personally I find it easier to read and it saves having to needlessly indent the entire process one level.  I've never seen any problems using this coding style with the FPGA synthesis tools I use (ISE, Quartus, Synplify).

#### Asynchronous Resets

To answer your bonus question regarding asynchronous resets - this is a little trickier.  Consider the following:

```
typedef struct packed {
    logic               a;
    logic               b;
} state_t;

state_t                 state;

always_ff @(posedge clk or negedge areset_n) begin
    if (~areset_n) begin
        state.a         <= 1'b0;
    end else begin
        state.a         <= data_a;
        state.b         <= data_b;
    end
end
```

We have a bit of a problem.  We don't want `state.b` to have a reset, but it's part of the same structure as `state.a` which is reset.  Being good engineers we use `always_ff` processes but this actually means we can't split the code into separate processes.  Besides, it would become very messy and error prone keeping track of which members are assigned in which process for a large state structure.

The above code actually synthesises to the following:

[image: example of gated input]

We can see that the `areset_n` signal acts as an enable to the `state.b` register.  Typically this isn't what we want, and since most FPGAs don't support this architecture natively the synthesis tool is forced to insert additional logic to emulate the enable:

[image]

This extra logic reduces timing margin and uses up precious resource.  Thankfully, there is a workaround:

```
always_ff @(posedge clk or negedge areset_n) begin
    if (~areset_n) begin
        state.a         <= 1'b0;
        state.b         <= 1'bx;
    end else begin
        state.a         <= data_a;
        state.b         <= data_b;
    end
end
```

Note that we have assigned `x` to `state.b` during the reset. As we can see, Quartus now synthesises our intended circuit:

[image]

#### Bonus Rant

As an aside, I'm not a big fan of being constrained to "standard practice" because the possibility that tools *might* get is wrong.  "Conventional wisdom" is often [incorrect or outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4774450/579887).

Be adventurous and push the tools to their limits. If you hit a bug in the tool or a limitation then raise a bug with the vendor and adjust your style to compensate.  Sure sometimes you'll spend time looking into a strange bug that turns out to be the fault of the toolchain but you should be looking at the output of your tools anyway.  The time spent will be more than saved by the improved levels of abstraction and re-use made available with some of the newer language features.

If more of us pushed to get new features supported or [participated in improving the languages](http://www.eda.org/twiki/bin/view.cgi/P1076/WebHome) then vendors wouldn't be able to get away with fobbing us all off with tools that are already 5-years out of date!  The level of conservatism in RTL development hampers innovation - we love complaining about the tools but we don't participate enough in making them better.

Comment: I did not think FPGAs designs often used asynchronous resets.

Comment: I also use "last assignment wins" for resets - the only downside I've found is continually explaining in code reviews!  If it were a more common idiom in the literature, that problem wouldn't occur :)

Comment: @MartinThompson look on the bright side - you actually _have_ code reviews!

Comment: @Morgan Altera recommends using asynchronous reset (though synchronously de-asserted) whereas Xilinx recommends synchronous throughout.

Comment: The diagrams look great! Which tools to draw them?

Answer (score 2):

As you have shown in the question for synchronous resets the basic pattern is:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (rst) begin
    out_valid <= 'b0;
  end
  else begin
    out_valid <= in_valid;
  end
end
```

With asynchronous reset:

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
  if (rst) begin
    out_valid <= 'b0;
  end
  else begin
    out_valid <= in_valid;
  end
end
```

I would not recommend mixing implying asyn reset flip-flops with non reset flip-flops as it easily looks like a typo that you forgot to add the resets. separating these two block seems like a good design separation. You are clearly separating control and data.

For the synchronous reset you should be ok to put the reset last as it is just a mux flop.

I would not recommend it though. The following apply a little stronger to the async case but the softer reasons apply to both.

Synthesis tools look for this pattern, when using your suggested method you may find that synthesis tools struggle or give incorrect results. Simulators and synthesis tools are often very different tools, using different code parsing engines under the hood. Just because it simulates ok does not mean it will synthesize ok.

Large designs may have many people working on them for months before it hits synthesis. If you have a dedicated Synthesis team they may be restricted to the version of tools that they can use based on internal quality control. Therefore even if you have proven to yourself that this works with the latest, or a particular version of the tools it may still end up causing a lot of extra work and extra design and synthesis cycles.

You may find that if company wide enforced linting tools and rules are put in place that this style would no longer pass a code quality review.

**Softer (not strict will it work) reasons**: 
An engineers role is to build something weighing up all the decision effecting cost, timescale and suitability for the required task. Using known working technology and methodologies where appropriate helps reduce risk and adds reliability to time scales.

Having industry standard coding practises, allows code to be handed over to anyone within the team or to external contractors. Using familiar coding patterns speeds up reading and understanding of code, which lead to a lower overall cost of design.

Comment: I suppose this is one of the differences between ASIC / FPGA development - FPGA designs can afford to use the 'cutting edge' language features because the cost of hitting an issue is (usually) far smaller.

Comment: "_months before it hits synthesis_": I synthesise each block as I go so there's a very small loop between writing code and running the tools. For each block a full simulation regression and synthesis run is executed automatically after every edit (by [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org)) with plots for test results, fMAX, synthesis warnings etc.  I can therefore see if/when I've introduced warnings or negatively impacted the fMAX just by glancing at a web-page. I would strongly recommend this way of working as you find issues earlier in the project and can therefore reduce the cost of fixing them.

Comment: Separating 'control' and 'data' into two separate processes is often a very clean solution. But sometimes the 'control' and 'data' need to respond to the same set of conditions. Having separate processes then means duplicating the code defining those conditions, which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: I completely understand your point about sticking to tried and tested methodologies. In this case, I still can't help question whether or not these concerns are well founded. Is there any evidence this style actually causes a problem with any mainstream synthesis tools?

Comment: @chiggs CI using Jenkins for hardware design, your living in the **future**. Quite envious. I do think build processes for hardware need to take on board more software practises.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can mix registers with sync reset with the ones without sync reset. How about the following:

```
always @(posedge clk)
begin
//Sync reset for out_valid
if (rst) out_valid <= 0;
else     out_valid <= in_valid;

//no sync reset for out_data
if (in_valid) out_data <= in_data + 1;
end
```

However, in case of async reset, if you write:

```
always @(posedge clk, posedge rst)
begin
  if (rst)      out_valid <= 0
  else          out_valid <= in_valid;

  if (in_valid) out_data <= in_data + 1;
end
```

you are implicitly tying rst and out_data together: the assignment to out_data would be incorrect when there is a posedge on rst, but no posedge on clk.

So as Morgan mentions, I think it is a good practice to clearly separate the registers with async reset from the ones without async reset.

Comment: A real circuit under synthesis would instantiate a flop without a reset pin, not tie it to 1. A flop with a reset pin is much larger than one without, and using resettable flops when not needed increases capacitive load on the reset network, and will make signal routing more congested. It's actually very common to instantiate flops without reset unless its directly needed.

Comment: I don't agree that the first two always blocks will synthesize to the same thing. In the first one, new data is only clocked into `out_data` when `rst` is specifically low. In the second always block, new data is clocked into `out_data` regardless of what `rst` is.

Comment: @Ari, I actually find this makes debugging during simulation easier because uninitialized registers stand out in the waveform viewer. If a downstream register clocks in an 'invalid' value shortly after reset, it will jump out as a likely bug because it will contain an unassigned (or unresolved) value.

Comment: @Tim: I have been working with a library that only has flops with async reset, which in that case the tool has no option other than connecting the asyn reset to 1, but the case of a more general library, I agree with you.

Comment: @mksuth: I'm not sure if having x values are always helpful, and what you mean by an invalid value. What if you have a cycle? The x values may never go away. In that case there circuit will run at an unknown state forever.

Comment: @mksuth: I misunderstood your question at first. I updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but I don't think it is wise to drive 'X in reset.  Though it will disconnect reset from the S/R or PRE/CLR, it will also lead to something you don't intend.  Often times we don't fully see all data dependencies in the design.  This leads to lack of determinism and likely big problems trying to close out timing in a high speed design.

simple case:

```
  1
  2   `define NC
  3 
  4   //`define SYNC_CLOCKING 1
  5 
  6   `define ALWAYS_FF( clk, rst ) \
  7     `ifdef SYNC_CLOCKING \
  8       always_ff @(posedge clk) \
  9     `else \
 10       `ifdef rst \
 11         always_ff @(posedge clk) \
 12       `else \
 13         always_ff @(posedge clk, posedge rst) \
 14       `endif \
 15     `endif
 16 
 17 module test (
 18   input  logic clk,
 19   input  logic rst,
 20   input  logic din,
 21   output logic [7:0] dout
 22 );
 23 
 24   typedef struct packed {
 25     logic         valid;
 26     logic [127:0] data;
 27   } intf;
 28 
 29   intf my_intf;
 30 
 31   logic [7:0] cnt;
 32 
 33   `ALWAYS_FF( clk, rst ) begin
 34     if( rst ) begin
 35       my_intf <= 'X;
 36       my_intf.valid <= 0;
 37       cnt  <= '0;
 38       dout <= '0;
 39     end else begin
 40       my_intf.valid <= din;
 41       if( my_intf.valid ) begin
 42         my_intf.data = my_intf.data + cnt;
 43       end
 44       if( din ) begin
 45         cnt  <= cnt + 2;
 46       end
 47       dout <= dout + my_intf.data;
 48     end
 49   end
 50 
 51 endmodule
```

There is an implicit dependency of data on rst through the valid.  Vivado will create this:

[Reset in Data Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXHLF.png)