# Bad coding style for a follower flip flop

Tags: verilog

The following is a code to capture data and the captured data is passed through a follower flip flop. The author of [Paper on Synchronous and Asynchronous Resets](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2003Boston_Resets.pdf) says that the the `rst_n` will be used as data enable for the second flip-flop, because both flip-flops are inferred from the same procedural block. Can anyone explain how will the simulator interpret this to be a `Load-data` signal only for the second flip flop?

```
module badFFstyle (
 output reg q2,
 input d, clk, rst_n
);

  reg q1;

  always @(posedge clk)
    if (!rst_n) q1 <= 1'b0;
    else begin
      q1 <= d;
      q2 <= q1;
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21477457/579887) for logic diagrams and a solution to mixing registers that are reset with registers that aren't into a single `always` block.

Comment: It makes more sense when it is labeled as enable signal rather than "load-data" used in paper. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rst_n` signal will be used as input data (along with input `d`) for `q1` output and as a clock enable for `q2` output. In order to understand the difference, you need to think **when** should the flip-flop sample it's input:

- `q1` will sample its input every clock cycle, when the input is `rst_n & d`.
- `q2` will sample its input only on clock cycles that occurs when `rst_n = 1` when the input is `q1`.

Meaning, that when `rst_n = 0`, the second flip-flop will hold to its value regardless to `d` and 1q1`.