# Do all Flip Flops in a design need to be resettable (ASIC)?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, system-verilog, asic

I'm trying to understand clock-reset in a chip. In a design what criteria are used to decide whether a flop should be assigned to a value (typically to zero) during reset?

```
always_ff @(posedge clk or negedge reset) begin : process_w_reset
   if(~reset) begin
      flop1 <= '0;
      ....
   end else begin
      if (condition) begin
         flop1 <= something ;
         .... 
      end
   end
end

always_ff @(posedge clk) begin : process_wo_reset
      if (condition) begin
         flop1 <= something ;
         .... 
      end
end
```

Is it a bad practice to not to reset a flop which is used later as a control signal in a comb logic? What if the design makes sure that the flop will have a valid value (0 or 1) assigned to it before its used in a comb logic block (i.e. in a if statement or in FSM comb logic) ?

I feel like it's better to always reset all the flops in the design. In that way there won't be any Xs after reset in the chip. However, it seems like for datapath logic, resetting flop might need not be a big deal as it'll be just pipe stages. However if a flop is in control path (i.e. FSM next state comb logic) then it should be reset to a default value. Is my understanding correct? I don't know much about DFT and not sure if it has any other implication.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that reset means asynchronous reset, as in the code examples.

The answer is partly opinion based, since a design can be made to work with reset of a minimum number of the Flip-Flops (FFs) and all of the FFs.

I suggest that a minimum number of FFs are reset, and typically that leads to reset of most FFs in the control path, and no reset of FFs in the data path.  The advantages of this approach are outlined below.

**Simulation** is often conservative with respect to propagation of uninitialized values, both for Verilog and VHDL, so it is like simulation can check both 0 and 1 values at once when the value is uninitialized.

Bugs due to FFs that are not reset, are therefore likely to show earlier in verification with simulation, and the designer thereby gets valuable feedback about wrong design assumptions, which may lead to corrections in the design that fixes other bugs.  Just resetting all the FFs is likely to hide such bugs.

It may seem like design and verification is just easier if all FFs are reset, both in control and data path, since it fixes all those "annoying" X propagation in the design.  But it requires an increased number of tests in order to verify all value combinations when X propagation is suppressed through reset.

**Implementation** gives a smaller load on the reset signal, so it is easier to meet timing of the reset net throughout the chip.

**DFT** (Design For Test) in general, then adding reset to the FFs will not aid DFT in finding nets stuck at reset value.  With a DFT scan chain approach where all the FFs are loaded through the scan chain, then the lack of reset on some FFs will not require more vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you need to think about where the 'X's will propagate in your simulation and which ones matter and which ones are don't care conditions. For example, if you have a block of logic which doesn't start operating until an enable bit is set, so long as the enable bit itself is set and enough upstream logic is reset so reset values will propagate through to the enabled logic in time, you are most likely OK with not reseting the logic in between. However, you do want to reset any logic that feeds back into itself, (for example state machines) otherwise the upstream resets will never be able to establish a known state in the feedback block.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Morten Zilmer that you should only reset flops that require resetting, although my background is more FPGA than ASIC.

It's worth pointing out there is a gotcha in Verilog / SystemVerilog - if you have a clocked process that drives registers that are reset *and* registers that aren't you will end up inferring a clock enable or an additional mux on the input of your flip-flop.

[image: Unintentional clock enable on state.b]

This is usually not what was intended.

There is a more detailed explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470497/verilog-vhdl-how-to-avoid-resetting-data-registers-within-a-single-always-bloc/21477457#21477457).  I also wrote a [blog post](http://potential.ventures/reset_roulette.html) outlining a mechanism for abstracting away synchronous/asynchronous and active high/low reset.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb, you should probably always reset control signals.

For data flops, resetting can cost you area, so it really depends on whether you care about area.

In recent years simulators started to support X propagation modes that allow you to catch some of the X issues in RTL (instead of gate level simulation).  It is a good practice to run these to make sure you don't have a reset problem with uninitialized sram or flops.