# Assigning x (dont care) to a register reset value or combinatorical output to improve area efficiency

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga

My question is regarding FPGA design - if I have some registers in my design that I dont care what will be their reset value, can I set the reset value to x? will that improve area efficiency (will the synthesizer be able to utilize this and generate the design in a more efficient way?)
For example,

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n) begin
    if(~reset_n) begin
        reg_1 <= 'x
    end
...
end
```

Edit:
And another question in a similar topic - assuming I have a state machine for example that I dont care what will some outputs be in some states - does setting them to 'x improve area efficiency?
for example, if I have a fsm with two states, STATE_1, STATE_2, and two outputs will the synthesis tool be able to utilize the following code:

```
always_comb begin
   case(state):
   STATE_1:begin
      out_1 = 1;
      out_2 = x;
   end
   STATE_2:begin
      out_1 = x;
      out_2 = 0;
   end
end
```

better than this:

```
always_comb begin
   case(state):
   STATE_1:begin
      out_1 = 1;
      out_2 = 0;
   end
   STATE_2:begin
      out_1 = 0;
      out_2 = 0;
   end
end
```

(under the assumption that I dont care what is out_2 in STATE_1, and what is out_1 in STATE_2).
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using `'x` in sequantial logic

Yes, Verilog-wise, you *could* use this syntax. However, in your particular example, it does not really make sense to do this and you could consider it to be a bad coding practive. Instead of explicitly assigning `'x`, you can also omit the asynchronous reset.

The following two processes will synthesise to the same flip-flop. I would personally recommend to use the latter style.

```
// Assigning 'x to tell synthesis tool that there is no reset value
always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n)
   if(~reset_n)
      reg_1 <= 'x;
   else
      reg_1 <= reg_1_next;


// Omitting the asynchronous reset from the sensitivity list to tell
// synthesis tool that there is no reset
always @(posedge clk)
   reg_1 <= reg_1_next;
```

In general: if you have different variables which must be either resetable or non-resetable, you should split their assignment into different `always`-blocks. This generally makes your code better readable. See the example below:

```
// Do NOT do this
always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n)
   if(~reset_n) 
   begin
      vld   <= 1'b0;
      reg_1 <= 'x;
   end
   else
   begin
      vld   <= vld_next;
      reg_1 <= reg_1_next;
   end


// Do this
always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n)
   if(~reset_n) 
      vld   <= 1'b0;
   else
      vld   <= vld_next;

always @(posedge clk)
    reg_1 <= reg_1_next;
```

---

### Bonus

Having said that, there are cases where it could make sense to assign `'x` in the reset condition to tell the synthesis tool to *not* generate resetable flops for particular variables. Please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21477457/7949378

Lets create an example, based on this answer. Lets say you have a struct with 1 valid-signal (`vld`) and 2 data signals (`data_a` and `data_b`). The data is only valid when `vld` is `1'b1`. In other words, we can save area by only resetting `vld` and not resetting `data_a` and `data_b`.

Now, we want to use the full potential of structs, and simply assign the full struct instead of the seperate members (see `struct_example_q <= struct_example_next;`). This means we *cannot* split this `always`-block into two seperate processes (like I recommened before). In that case, we must explicitly tell the synthesis tool to *not* reset the data signals.

See the code below:

```
   typedef struct {
      logic        vld;
      logic [31:0] data_a;
      logic [31:0] data_b;
  } struct_example_t;

  struct_example_t struct_example_next;
  struct_example_t struct_example_q;

  always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n)
     if (!reset_n)
     begin
         /**
          * Only reset the valid-bit
          * We could use '{default:'x} to simplify this even further
          **/
         struct_example_q.data_a <= 'x;
         struct_example_q.data_b <= 'x;
         struct_example_q.vld    <= 1'b0;
     end
     else
     begin
         struct_example_q <= struct_example_next;
     end
```

---

## Using `'x` in combinatorial logic

Lets first look at your RTL:

```
always_comb begin
   case(state):
   STATE_1:begin
      out_1 = 1;
      out_2 = x;
   end
   STATE_2:begin
      out_1 = x;
      out_2 = 0;
   end
end
```

I want to note that this is not really the best example. Assuming that the FSM is full—i.e., that `STATE_1` and `STATE_2` are the only two states `state` can take—you would achieve exactly the same with the code below, assuming you don't case anyway about `out_1` and `out_2` in the other states.

```
always_comb begin
    out_1 = 1;
    out_2 = 0;
end
```

Now, for the sake of the example, lets assume that we cannot rewrite this. In that case, you should set default values before your case-statement. This prevents the synthesis logic from infering latches in your don't-care state, but it also helps you to *not* run into issues with `'x` once you start doing gate-level simulations (GLS). Using your example, you RTL would look like the code below. (Again note that the case here is kind of redundant.)

```
always_comb begin
   out_1 = 1;
   out_2 = 0;

   case(state):
   STATE_1:begin
      out_1 = 1;
   end
   STATE_2:begin
      out_2 = 0;
   end
end
```

You will see that this strategy makes sense once you have more elaborate FSMs.

---

### Bonus

I want to give an example where using `unique` or `priority` can make sense (instead of using `'x` as default value). Take a look at the RTL below and assume that `select == 3'b0` will never occur:

```
always_comb
begin
    out_1 = 'x;

    case (1'b1)
        select[0]: out_1 = a & b;
        select[1]: out_1 = a ^ b;
        select[2]: out_1 = a | b;
    endcase
end
```

Setting a default value for `out_1` will prevent the logic from inferring a latch (since it does not know that `select == 3'b0` can never occur). Furthermore, the `'x` here will help the synthesis tool to optimize this logic (*not necessarily w.r.t. area!*). However, as we discussed before, using `'x` is generally considered to be bad practice.

Instead of using a default value, you can use the `priority` keyword to tell the synthesis tool that all  valid cases have been listed and that the tool must evaluate your cases in order. Because of that, the following case will also be considered as full:

```
always_comb
    priority case (1'b1)
        select[0]: out_1 = a & b;
        select[1]: out_1 = a ^ b;
        select[2]: out_1 = a | b;
    endcase
```

If you, additionally, can be sure that `select` is a onehot signal (`$countones(select) == 1`), you can use the `unique` keyword. This will tell the synthesis tool that this is full-parallel case

```
always_comb
    unique case (1'b1)
        select[0]: out_1 = a & b;
        select[1]: out_1 = a ^ b;
        select[2]: out_1 = a | b;
    endcase
```

Note that simulators will trry to enforce these assumptions by throwing errors at you if you violate the assumptions that are necessary to use `priority` or `unique`.

Comment: Hi @fptech20, you could do this in combinational logic and the synthesis tool will optimize this. However, I would generally recommend to _not_ do this, since it could cause mismatches once you start running gate-level simulations. Instead of assigning `'x`, I would recommend to look into the (System)Verilog keywords `unique`, `unique0`,  and `priority`.

Comment: Could you please see my edit with the additional question? I dont see how unique/priority can be helpful here...

Comment: @fptech20, see my edit.

Comment: Great! that answered my question fully. Just another small thing - assuming what I want to optimize is area and that I dont have any tight timing constraint - do you have any good advice on stuff that can reduce area? any design rules or synthesis optimizations (I'm using synplify pro) that can be useful?