# Verilog Blocking Assignment

Tags: verilog, blocking, nonblocking

I am somewhat new to Verilog. I know that in a Clock Process we should use non blocking assignments, and in a Non Clock processes, we use blocking assignments.

I have came across this code, when I was reading someone else's code.

```
reg iowrb_int,iowrb_met;
reg iordb_int,iordb_met;
always@(*)
begin
  iowrb_int <= iowrb_met;
  iordb_int <= iordb_met;

  iowrb_met <= iowr_bar;
  iordb_met <= iord_bar;
end
```

I am really not sure about the above code ! I don't think it is doing any registering, correct? Would it mean anything to have a non-blocking in a always@(*) statement ?

Is there any difference in using blocking vs non-blocking in a always@(*) statement ?

Comment: The idea that you should only use nonblocking assignments in clocked processes is a very unfortunate myth. See my award winning answer here :-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/4774450/574895

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is:

- a blocking assignment is executed before the next assignment i.e. it blocks the execution of the next statement.
- non-blocking assignments execute in parallel i.e. they don't block the execution of the statement following them.

Suppose a = 2 and b = 3 then non-blocking assignments:

```
a <= 4;
b <= a;
```

results in a = 4 and b = 2  - value of a before assignment

But

```
a = 4;
b = a;
```

Will result in a=4 and b=4 - value of a after the blocking assignment completes.

A variable getting synthesized to a register (latch or flip-flop) vs. combinatorial logic depends on the sensitivity list of the always block. It does not depend on use of blocking or non-blocking assignment.

For example:

```
always @(*) begin
  if (enable)
     q = d;
end
```

This will result in a D-latch since assignment to q is not specified for when enable==0 so it needs to remember is last assignment.

While

```
always @(*) begin
  if (enable)
    q = d;
  else
    q = f;
end
```

This will result in a mux (combinatorial logic) since assignment to q is specified for both cases of enable and so q need not remember anything.

Comment: Thanks. So in the example that I provided, since it is an  always@(*) statement, then it will not generate a register, correct?

Comment: That depends on the code inside the always statement.  I will update the answer.

Comment: @jamish a flip-flop can not be implied from `always @*`

Comment: @Morgan is correct. No flip-flops, but latches can be implied from `always @*`

Comment: I would avoid asking about registers as it is to easily confused, with the `reg` type, and uses flip-flop and latches

Comment: Okay I think it makes more sense now. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

The blocking vs non-blocking is so that your gate level (synthesis) matches your RTL simulation. Using a different one to alter the behaviour of the simulation as far as I know will not effect synthesis and therefore the behaviour of gate-level.

`<=` non-blocking effectively take a temporary copy of the copy right-hand side, and make the `=` blocking assignment at the end of the timestep.

```
a <= b;
b <= a;
```

is equivalent to:

```
a_temp = b;
b_temp = a;
//
a = a_temp;
b = b_temp;
```

The example uses combinatorial logic, that is it contains no state, so all inputs must be defined by all outputs.

```
always@* begin
  iowrb_int <= iowrb_met;
  iordb_int <= iordb_met;
  iowrb_met <= iowr_bar;
  iordb_met <= iord_bar;
end
```

When the right hand side updates the block should be retriggered. Since iowrb_met is on both sides I am not sure what this implies interms of electrical connectivity.

while `<=` implies copying to a temp location, combinatorial logic does not have this capability, it is always and continuously driven by the assignment.

I think in simulation you effectively have this:

```
always@* begin
  iowrb_int_temp = iowrb_met;
  iordb_int_temp = iordb_met;
  iowrb_met      = iowr_bar;
  iordb_met      = iord_bar;
  iowrb_int      = iowrb_int_temp;
  iordb_int      = iordb_int_temp;
end
```

In hardware you would have:

```
always@* begin
  iowrb_int = iowrb_met;  //= iowr_bar;
  iordb_int = iordb_met;  //= iord_bar;
  iowrb_met = iowr_bar;
  iordb_met = iord_bar;
end
```

Where `iowrb_int` is effectively the same as `iowrb_met`

Flip-flops are implied using `always @(posedge clk`
Combinatorial logic is implied using `always @*`  but latches can be implied when the output is not fully defined from inputs.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Comment: Please, one more question: Is `iowrb_int = iowr_bar` true in your last example?

Comment: @user35443, yes, in hardware, or after synthesis all statements are in parallel. when iowrb_met changes value the block will be re-evaluated, leading to `iowrb_int = iowr_bar`

Answer (score 1):

By *only* changing to code to blocking assignments it may synthesize to latches and/or create logical equivalency check mismatches depending on the tools handle.

This is how it looks through the scheduler:

- With blocking:

  1. The `*_int` signals are assigned
  2. The `*_met` signals are assigned
  3. Move on to the next time step.

     - `*_int` keeps the non-updated values of `*_met`
- With non-blocking:

  1. The `*_int` signals are assigned
  2. The `*_met` signals are assigned
  3. A change to `*_met` is detected causes a loop back the the *Active* region of the scheduler
  4. Re-assign the `*_int` signals
  5. Re-assign the `*_int` signals
  6. Move on to the next time step.

     - `*_int` has the same values as `*_met`
     - Waste CPU time to reprocessing. This is not important on a small project, but can add noticeable overhead used throughout a large project.

The correct, logical equivalent, and CPU friendly way would be to revers the assignment order (assign `*_met` before `*_int`):

```
always@(*)
begin
  iowrb_met = iowr_bar;
  iordb_met = iord_bar;

  iowrb_int = iowrb_met;
  iordb_int = iordb_met;
end
```

1. The `*_int` signals are assigned
2. The `*_met` signals are assigned
3. Move on to the next time step.

   - `*_int` has the same values as `*_met`

***OR*** use `*_bar` as the assigning value (i.e. if a==b and b==c, then a==b and a==c):

```
always@(*)
begin
  iowrb_int = iowr_bar;
  iordb_int = iord_bar;

  iowrb_met = iowr_bar;
  iordb_met = iord_bar;
end
```

1. The `*_int` and `*_met` signals are assigned
2. Move on to the next time step.

   - `*_int` has the same values as `*_met`

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, changing to blocking assignments here will actually not work. Using blocking assignments in combinational always blocks (which is the recommendation) require you to put assignments in the right order.

Using non-blocking assignments in combinational always blocks may seem attractive, because you can then have assignments in any order, like in VHDL. Besides performance, one good reason to avoid this is that it doesn't work with `always_comb`. This code does not work:

```
always_comb begin
  tmp <= in;
  out <= tmp;
end
```

The reason is that `tmp` will not be part of the sensitivity list. It will work as expected if you use `always @(*)`, `always @(tmp, in)` or replace with blocking assignments.