# Do For Loops sum between or after iterations? Verilog

Tags: verilog

I will use this example code to ask some general questions about for loops.

The following code is intended to create a simple multiplier function between two 3-bit numbers, `a` and `b`:

```
1   function [5:0] mult;
2     input [2:0] a,b;
3     reg [5:0] r;
4     integer i;
5   begin
6     if(a[0] == 1)
7       r = b;
8     else
9       r = 0;
10    for(i=1; i<=2; i = i+1) begin
11       if(a[i]==1)
12         r = r + b <<i;
13    end
14    mult = r;  // set function name equal to product
15  end
16  endfunction
```

I believe this gives the desired result but I can only make sense of it if:

1. Lines `7` or `9` (depending on line `6` obviously) *add* to the *end* result of the 'for loop' (which begins on line `10`)
2. The definition of `r` from lines `7` or `9` is **not** carried into line `12` in the 'for loop'
3. Each iteration (or 'step') of the 'for loop' does not carry its calculated value for `r` from a *prior* index value `i` into a *subsequent* index value `i`

If these three conclusions are correct then I have these questions:

- Do 'For Loops' sum their iterations after all possible steps have been made?
- Do 'For Loops' *not* carry information about an identifier *within* the 'for loop' *derived from one step* to the next despite the same identifier appearing in both steps (`r` in this case)? Referring to line `12` here.
- How should I have known conclusion #1 was true? What is the underlying rule(s)?

Finally, I understand 'for loops' don't necessarily add, they simply repeat if the condition is met. Only in this example is the 'for loop' adding.

Comment: I haven't tested it. It was taken from [Intel's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJGvZSlsLKs) tutorial on Verilog basics. The time stamp is 38:09. I believe the number of `end`s is correct. There should be 2 total: one for the `for` and one for `begin`. Note: my code is slightly different from intel's for simplicity. Theirs deals with 8-bit numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic here is very simple. Consider `a=3 -> 011` and `b=5 -> 101`. You can calculate it use following scheme:

```
   101 (b=5)
x  011 (a=3)
 -----
   101 (t1)
  101  (t2)
+000   (t3)
 -----
=01111 (15)
```

Line `7` and `9` are used to calculate the value denoted as `t1` and `for-loop` is used to calculate `t2` and `t3`. So:

- Line `6`: `a[0]=1`. Thus, `r=00101` in line `7`.
- Line `11` and `i=1`: `a[1]=1`. Thus, `r=00101 + 101<<1 = 00101 + 1010 = 01111`.
- Line `11` and `i=2`: `a[2]=0`. Thus, `r=01111`.

You should read about [blocking and non-blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22565904/2572285) assigments in Verilog.

Comment: @Qiu Your answer is very helpful. So should `r+(b<<i)` be replaced in the code then? That would seem like we are making the left shift *before* adding which seems uncessary(?) Also, I am still wondering if about the underling rule to #1 of my conclusions? How does the code know to just add `t1` in your example to the result of the for loop (`t2` and `t3`)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the `for` loop in your example and a `for` loop in any other programming language. It works absolutely the same. All operators inside the `always` block are executed sequentially, there is no other dependency mechanism between them other than the line numbers.

> Lines 7 or 9 (depending on line 6 obviously) add to the end result of the 'for loop' (which begins on line 10)

This is a normal `if` operator, as in any other language. It is executed first and assigns an initial value to `r`, depending on the value of `a[0]`.

> The definition of r from lines 7 or 9 is not carried into line 12 in the 'for loop'

not sure what you mean here. The previous `if` operator sets the initial value of `r`, which is used in the first taken `if` statement in the loop  as `r = r + b <<i;`. The right hand side of the expression contains `r` and first time around it contains the initial value.

> Each iteration (or 'step') of the 'for loop' does not carry its calculated value for r from a prior index value i into a subsequent index value i

As in any programming language, the value of `r` will be updated every iteration where the `if` statement is taken. This updated value will be used at the next iteration of the loop in the same expression `r = r + b <<i;`.

> If these three conclusions are correct then I have these questions:

your conclusions are *incorrect*. So you have to re-think your further questions.