# Verilog blocking and non-blocking in a sequence

Tags: verilog, blocking, nonblocking

I have the following in Verilog:

```
reg a;

always @ (clk)
begin
  a = 0;
  a <= 1;
  $display(a);
end
```

What value of literal 'a' would show me? Is that 0 or 1?

Comment: Have you tried simulating it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to interpret blocking vs non blocking assignments in Verilog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653284/how-to-interpret-blocking-vs-non-blocking-assignments-in-verilog)

Comment: @Qiu, this is not duplicate of that. It is close to that, but I want to see others' answers. --- I know the following about scheduling semantics in Verilog simulators: the order in which events are scheduled to execute is as below: 1- active events such as blocking assignment and RHS calculation of non-blocking assignments. 2- Inactive assignments, and 3- Nonblocking assign update. For the above example, I believe $display may show 0 or 1, depending on when display gets executed.

Comment: @Ari, can you recommend a good simulator in Mac that is free for use so I can simulate this?

Comment: There's a simple answer to your (good) question, but you've posted code that has obviously never been near a simulator. If you fixed it first, you'd be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: seems like you know the answer to your question  ..If you know about scheduling events this question should be fairly  straight forward

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw: The question seems to be about when the argument to `$display` is evaluated

Comment: this question needs more credit than what it might seem

Comment: @Mehdi: I don't know a simulator on mac, but you can use this free online simulator: http://www.edaplayground.com/ which is based on Modelsim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verilog simulation occurs in 5 queues as stated in IEEE 1364-1995 § 5.3, IEEE 1364-2001 § 5.3, and IEEE 1364-2005 § 11.3:

- ***Active Event*** (before `#0`)

  - Evaluate RHS of all non-blocking assignment
  - Evaluate RHS and change LHS of all blocking assignments
  - Evaluate RHS and change LHS of all continuous assignments
  - Evaluate inputs and change outputs of all primitives
  - Evaluate and print output from `$display` and `$write`
- ***Inactive Event*** (after `#0`)

  - Evaluate RHS after `#0` delay, otherwize same processes as ***Active Event***
  - Callback procedures scheduled with PLI routines such as `tf_synchronize()`*(deprecated in IEEE 1364-2005)* and `vpi_register_cb(cbReadWriteSynch)`
- ***NBA Update***

  - Change LHS of all non-blocking assignments
- ***Monitor Event***

  - Evaluate and print output from `$monitor` and `$strobe`
  - Call PLI with `reason_rosynchronize`*(deprecated in IEEE 1364-2005)*
- ***Future***

  - Events to occur at some future simulation time

Since  `$display` occurs before the non-blocking assignment is assigned , the value will be 0. Note the order of execution may change in each queue.