# Can Verilog variables be given local scope to an always block?

Tags: scope, verilog, system-verilog

I sometimes find it useful to use blocking assignments for "local variables" inside clocked always blocks. This can help cut down on repeated code.

To avoid accidentally using the same variable in a different always block (which can be non-deterministic for simulation), I'd like to give it local scope. Is there a nice synthesizable way of doing this?

Something like:

```
module sum3(
  input            clk,
  input      [7:0] in1,
  input      [7:0] in2,
  input      [7:0] in3,
  output reg [7:0] result,
  output reg [7:0] result_p1);

  begin :sum
    reg [7:0] sum_temp; // local variable
    always @(posedge clk) begin
      sum_temp   = in1 + in2 + in3;
      result    <= sum_temp;
      result_p1 <= sum_temp + 1;
    end
  end

endmodule
```

(ModelSim seems to be okay with this, but Synplify doesn't seem to like it.)

Comment: To clarify for others: please note that a begin/end block needs to be ***named*** to create a scope.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure of the semantics in plain Verilog, but according to the [SystemVerilog LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) section 6.21:

> Variable declarations shall precede any statements within a procedural block.

Therefore the following is legal syntax in SystemVerilog:

```
module sum3(
  input            clk,
  input      [7:0] in1,
  input      [7:0] in2,
  input      [7:0] in3,
  output reg [7:0] result,
  output reg [7:0] result_p1);

  always @(posedge clk) begin : sum
    reg [7:0] sum_temp; // local variable (scope limited to process)
    sum_temp   = in1 + in2 + in3;
    result    <= sum_temp;
    result_p1 <= sum_temp + 1;
  end

endmodule
```

Note that I have moved the variable declaration `sum_temp` into the process, thereby limiting the scope and removing the need for the named `sum` block.  This compiles on Modelsim and Riviera (example on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/D56)).

If your tool doesn't support this syntax, raise a bug!

Answer (score 3):

Despite the common guideline, using blocking assignments inside clocked always blocks is ok, and sometime as you mentioned useful. See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4774450/1383356

Some tools however, may not support local variables defined inside a begin-end block.

Alternatively, you can try putting some or all of the the body of the always block in a task:

```
task SUM_TASK();
  reg [7:0] sum_temp; // local variable
  sum_temp   = in1 + in2 + in3;
  result    <= sum_temp;
  result_p1 <= sum_temp + 1;
endtask

always @(posedge clk) begin
  SUM_TASK();
end
```

Verilog tasks can have access to global variables as well as local ones. Also, they can include non-blocking assignments.

Answer (score 3):

The standard sythesizable way is to use a continuous assignment with a `wire`:

```
module sum3(
  input        clk,
  input  [7:0] in1,
  input  [7:0] in2,
  input  [7:0] in3,
  output reg [7:0] result,
  output reg [7:0] result_p1);

    wire [7:0] sum_temp = in1 + in2 + in3;
    always @(posedge clk) begin
      result    <= sum_temp;
      result_p1 <= sum_temp + 1;
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: This works for this simple (and contrived) example, but in more complex cases this can hurt readability (assignments end up far away from where the variables are used). Also, there are cases when you may want to use different intermediate values of the "local variable".

Comment: @mksuth I won't hurt readability. `assignments end up far away from where the variables are used`: What do you mean by far away? It is the job of placer and router which you don't need to worry about. If you wanna use `different intermediate values` use another `reg` for it inside the always block.

Comment: @tod, I am only referring to the human readability of the code. If the `always` block occupied hundreds of lines of code, then using a `wire` for an "intermediate variable", could result in the assignment being far away (in the code) from where the `wire` is actually used inside the `always` block. In my opinion, the code is more readable when the assignment of the variable and the use of the variable are grouped together in the code.

Comment: **grouped together**: provided it is doable. Btw, **hundreds of lines of code** in one `always` block is the problem. Why don't you break it into multiple always blocks wherever suitable? Also you may use loops...

Comment: @tod: Also, I believe this pollutes the module namespace, which will be a problem if you want simple names for the temp variable like "i" (think of a array subscript).