# What is the difference between = and <= in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

What is the difference between `=` and `<=` in this code?  Also, how do I print the value of `data`?

```
    module always_example();
reg clk,reset,enable,q_in,data;

always @ (posedge clk)
if (reset)  begin
   data <= 0;
end else if (enable) begin   
   data <= q_in;
end
// if i put     $print("data=%d", data);   there is error
endmodule
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interpret blocking vs non blocking assignments in Verilog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653284/how-to-interpret-blocking-vs-non-blocking-assignments-in-verilog)

Comment: @Greg It is duplicate only if one already knows what `=` and `<=` mean.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

<= is a nonblocking assignment.  It is used to describe sequential logic, like in your code example.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2012, section 10.4.2 "Nonblocking procedural assignments".

= is for blocking assignments.  It is used to describe combinational logic.

See also [Nonblocking Assignments in Verilog Synthesis, Coding Styles That Kill!](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf)

You can use `$display` instead of `$print` to print the value of variables.  See also IEEE Std 1800-2012, section 21.2 "Display system tasks".

Answer (score 36):

= is blocking statement. In an `always` block, the line of code will be executed only after it's previous line has executed. Hence, they happens one after the other, just like combinatoral logics in loop.

<= is non-blocking in nature. This means that in an `always` block, every line will be executed in parallel. Hence leading to implementation of sequential elements.

Comment: "every line will be executed in parallel. Hence leading to implementation of sequential elements". Could you explain this, I am even more confused. Shouldn't sequential components be serially executed?