# fpga programming using verilog

Tags: case, verilog, fpga

Case statement in **verilog**. I don't understand how this code works

```
 if(cpld_cs & cpld_we)
            begin
                case(ifc_a27_31)
                    `RSTCON1:   begin
                                    sw_rst_r <= ifc_ad0_7[0];
                                    ddr_rst_r <= ifc_ad0_7[1];
                                    ec1_rst_r <= ifc_ad0_7[2];
                                    ec2_rst_r <= ifc_ad0_7[3];
                                    xgt1_rst_r <= ifc_ad0_7[6];
                                    xgt2_rst_r <= ifc_ad0_7[7];
```

Comment: What your research so far tells you?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take few moments to take a [tour] and also read [ask] to get better answers for your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Just look up documentation. I am no verilog expert but checking documentation you can get that

```
            case(ifc_a27_31)
                `RSTCON1:   begin
```

is just simple case where if value of `ifc_a27_31` is `RSTCON1` then commands

```
                                sw_rst_r <= ifc_ad0_7[0];
                                ddr_rst_r <= ifc_ad0_7[1];
                                ec1_rst_r <= ifc_ad0_7[2];
                                ec2_rst_r <= ifc_ad0_7[3];
                                xgt1_rst_r <= ifc_ad0_7[6];
                                xgt2_rst_r <= ifc_ad0_7[7];
```

are getting executed.
And of course

```
 sw_rst_r <= ifc_ad0_7[0];
```

is just non-blocking assignment.

Information I took from [Case Statement](http://verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00004.htm) and [What is the difference between = and <= in verilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435420/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-verilog)

Comment: Thanks for your effort.

Comment: this is **not** `just assignment`. It is the `non-blocking` assignment which has a specific semantic. Please check verilog manual.

Comment: @Serge Yes I know, and it is obvious from link I added. I will correct that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

verilog `case` syntax consists of a case expression or selector expression `(ifc_a37_31)` and case items with label expression (macro `RSTCON1` in your case) and action items. When `afr_a37_31` matches the value of the macro, the statements in the `begin` .. `end` block will be executed sequentially.

The case statement might have multiple case items, the first one which matches the selector will be active and its block will be executed.

There is also a `default` clause which will get executed if no matches are found.

Now in your case it looks like this is a part of a latch or a flop definition, since 'non-blocking' assignments are used there. It is ok to miss some conditions and/or the `default` statement in such a case.

you might see other variants of the `case` statement, like `casex` or `casez`. Syntax for all of them is similar, the difference is in the ways the selector is compared to the label.

in system verilog there are more, like `unique` of `priority` cases or `case inside`.

So, you need to go through a tutorial to get more information about all this.