# unable to enter if else statement

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I wrote a code like this:

```
   if (a) begin
   //some coding
   end
   else begin
   stage = 0;
           if (b) begin
                  if (stage == 0) begin
                  stage = 1;
                  end
                  else if (stage == 1) begin
                  stage = 2;
                  end
                  else begin
                  stage = 0;
            end
            else
            // some coding
            end
    end
```

When stage is 1, the code inside stage == 1 cannot perform. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the error? Can you show some stimulus?

Comment: Is this inside an `always @*` or `always @(posedge clk)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Put like this, it cannot work.
You have to put it in a process, i.e. always@(something).

```
//adding a signal needed
reg[1:0] stage_next;     

always@(*)begin//Means that everytime an event occurs in one of the signals used in the following code,
               //the code contained in this process will be executed
    if (a) begin
   //some coding
    end
    else begin
    stage = 0;
            if (b) begin
                  if (stage == 0) begin
                  //stage = 1;//this assignement will produce a combinatorial loop
                            //when the value of 'stage' changes the process(always@(*))
                            //will be re-executed. You have to assign another signal(stage_next here)
                  stage_next = 1
                  end
                  else if (stage == 1) begin
                  //stage = 2;//Same here
                  stage_next = 2;
                  end
                  else begin
                  //stage = 0;//Same here
                  stage_next = 0;
            end
            else
            // some coding
            end
    end
end
//The other process where stage will take the value of stage_next should be synchronous
//It will break the combinatorial loop
always@(posedge clk)
  stage <= stage_next;
```

Answer (score 0):

The blocking assignment `stage = 0` before `if (b)` is forcing stage to zero before the `stage == 1` condition is evaluated.

Use non-blocking assignment (`<=`) to all `stage` assignments and you should get the expected behavior. See [How to interpret blocking vs non blocking assignments in Verilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4653284/1959732)
Your code block must be within an sequential block (clock triggering, ex: `always @(posedge clk)`)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your indentation is misleading, try instead:

```
   always @(*)
   if (a) begin
   //some coding
   end
   else begin
           stage = 1;
           if (b) begin
                  if (stage == 0) begin
                      stage = 1;
                  end
                  else if (stage == 1) begin
                      stage = 2;
                  end
                  else begin
                      stage = 0;
                  end
            end // Your code did not have this end
            else begin // This begin was also missing
            // some coding
            end
    end
```

So I think you are saying if you have that code, then you don't see stage == 2???
Because without those code modifications you'll have the else binding to an unexpected if