# Do not mix blocking and non-blocking assignments in the same block?

Tags: verilog

Is it true or false in Verilog?
I do not understand what does it mean by mixing..Does it changes the output directly if it works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653284/how-to-interpret-blocking-vs-non-blocking-assignments-in-verilog) SO question.

Comment: It's not even synthesizable though it may work in simulation.

Comment: Yes I think it may be related to synthesizability only, not simulation

Answer (score 3):

The rule needs to be clarified.

Do not assign the *same variable* using both blocking and non-blocking assignments within the same block. The problem usually manifests itself when describing an asynchronous reset.

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
  if (!reset)
    q = 0;
  else
    q < = d;
```

If the two events occur at the same time, but `q<= d` gets processed before the `q=0`, then there is a pending update to q after it gets set to 0, so that gets lost. There are a number of other scenarios.

Comment: Can you please be more clear? When the TWO events (I guess you are talking about posedge clk and negedge rst) occur at the same time, only q = 0 will get executed. q <= d will not. Why are you talking that q <= d might execuute and then q=0 might execute?

Comment: Yes, those are the two events. `q<=d` might get executed because `rst` is still 1, the `negedge rst` has not happened yet.